# How to login with Laravel 5.3 using a table other than 'users'?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

I'have already got a table name 'members' which contains fields like -

memberID,

password (md5 hashed),

resetToken,

etc.

I want to login using memberID and password. I tried `Auth::attempt($credentials)` and `Auth::login($user)` but could not make it work.

Comment: check `app/config/auth.php`

Comment: have you create modal for members table ?

Comment: yes, I've tried creating a Member model and changing config/auth.php file.
but can't find what I've been missing

Comment: @Al-aminNowshad. Could you describe your error message that your auth does not work.

Comment: already solved the problem, thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

You need to change in auth.php file

```
 'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

In this code you need change User model to your specified model
like

```
'model' => App\YourModel::class,
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a reference to the model `User` in `config/auth.php` file so you can change it as follows:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
],
```

As for me what I do is, I maintain the model name as `User` but inside the model I define my table name. In your case:
In the `User` model you can do:

```
protected $table = 'members';
```